# How to check overdue tasks in SharePoint task list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks, task-list, workflow-tasks-list

I'm attempting to build a workflow for a task list. When a new item is added to the list, I want the workflow to begin looping to check if the task has been completed or not.

If the task is not completed on time, I want to update the Task Progress field in the list to "Late." Otherwise, I want this field to read "On Track"

Here is my SharePoint logic:
[image]

When it runs, the Task Progress field remains blank.

I clicked on the workflow itself and found this error:
[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help. Cheers!

Comment: The `Task Status` field is out of the box column or custom column?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti The Task Status field is out of the box. The only custom column is the Task Progress field. Thanks for the response

Comment: The log shows the `TaskStatus` internal name not found. The internal name of `Task Status` field is `Status`. Could you refresh the workflow from SharePoint Designer using (Green Refresh Icon) from the top ribbon and check errors.